# How to get magento customer session values in root index file for switching store view

Tags: session, magento, multisite

I have created 2 store views for my magento website running under magento 1.9.2, I need to use the same domain name for both of the websites. When a customer logged in, I need to change the store view to the second one. I need to check the customer session in the index.php file in root directory. But when I follow the below changes to index.php, I end up with an error

```
$store_id = 1;
//Check customer session here 
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){ // Error occurs here
    $customer       = Mage::getModel('customer/session')->getCustomer();            
    $customerId     = $customer->getId(); 
    // $storeid  get logged in customer storeid may from customer custom attribute value added on admin edit form
    // $store_id value get changed here
}



Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store_id);
umask(0);
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

if($store_id == 2)
$mageRunCode = 'mysecondshop';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

When I check the issue, I find that we cannot use Mage::getSingleton before Mage::run, but for my current situation for switching between stores, I need to get logged in user details before mage run. Is there any way to achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In magento it is not possible to check session data unless Mage::run is initilaized. We need to do some temporary storage like cookie to achieve this. Hopefully the below steps will make it works.

Create a custom module with observer for saving, clearing and checking cookie. Your config.xml file is given below

```
<!--------------------------------------------------------------------->
<customer_login>
  <observers>
    <Company_Modulename_model_customer_login>
      <class>Company_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
      <method>afterCustomerLoggedIn</method>
    </Company_Modulename_model_customer_login>
  </observers>
</customer_login>
<customer_logout>
  <observers>
    <Company_Modulename_model_customer_logout>
      <class>Company_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
      <method>afterCustomerLoggedOut</method>
    </Company_Modulename_model_customer_logout>
  </observers>
</customer_logout>
<controller_action_layout_load_before>
  <observers>
    <Company_Modulename_model_layoutload_observer>
      <class>Company_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
      <method>beforeLoadLayout</method>
    </Company_Modulename_model_layoutload_observer>
  </observers>
</controller_action_layout_load_before>
<!--------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

Observer implementation is given below

```
public function afterCustomerLoggedIn(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
    $cid      = $customer->getid();
    $webId    = $customer->getWebsiteId();
    Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('_storeuid',$cid, 60*60*24*1);  // Create cookie
    Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('_storeid',$webId, 60*60*24*1); // Create cookie

}


public function afterCustomerLoggedOut(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
    $cid      = $customer->getid();
    $webId    = $customer->getWebsiteId();  
    Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('_storeuid','0', 1); // Clear cookie
    Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('_storeid','0', 1);  // Clear cookie

}
```

Before rendering pages

```
public function beforeLoadLayout(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{


    $cookieValue = Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('_storeuid');
    $baseurl = Mage::getBaseUrl();

    if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){ // For more security , if someone change the cookie value


        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/session')->getCustomer();          
        $webId    = $customer->getWebsiteId();
        $cid      = $customer->getId();

        if( $cookieValue != $cid ){

                Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('_storeuid',$cid, 60*60*24*1);
                Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('_storeid',$webId, 60*60*24*1);
                header("Location: ".$baseurl); exit;

       }
    }else{

        if( (isset($cookieValue)) && ($cookieValue > 0)  ){ // Clear cookie if session is cleared

            Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('_storeuid','0', 1);
            Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('_storeid','0', 1);
            header("Location: ".$baseurl); exit;

        }

    }
}
```

And Finally in index.php , you can check the cookie for switching the store value for loggedin customers

```
$store_id = 1;
if( (isset($_COOKIE['_storeur'])) && ($_COOKIE['_storeur'] > 0)  ){
    $store_id = $_COOKIE['_storeur'];
}

$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

if($store_id == 2 ) $mageRunCode = 'store2';
if($store_id == 3 ) $mageRunCode = 'store3';
//....................
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need :)